# How do Kubernetes Deployments store revisions?

Tags: kubernetes

The DaemonSet and StatefulSet controllers use [ControllerRevisions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-daemon/rollback-daemon-set/#understanding-daemonset-revisions) to work out the previous desired state when rolling back - how do Deployments do this?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? because as it is I can say "`deployments` brings up the new instances and when it's ready it kills the old one, one at a time" like this example: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/. Is this what you want to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReplicaSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/), which one can see listed at the bottom of a `kubectl describe deployment $foo`, and is -- to the best of my knowledge -- how `kubectl rollout status` and `kubectl rollout undo` works under the covers